# AJAX notify if there's a redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple ajax script to load the content of a file.
I want to show an alert if there's a redirect

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#div1").load("demo_test.txt #p1");
    });
});
```

Any help ? Thanks in advance

Comment: No, ajax cannot detect redirect. It just follows them. After all, that's what you have the redirect for, don't you?

Comment: I'm just making a PHP CMS with an AJAX Administration, and I have a security script that disconnect the user after 30 minutes, so I want to prevent this with an Alert "You've been disconnected"

Answer (score 1):

The $.load function works like this, you have to call it like this:

```
$("#div1").load("demo_test.txt", function() {
   alert("Load was performed.");
});
```